# Blurry resolution when uploading DEM 5ft data onto QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, mapping, resolution

I am creating a map for the nature preserve I work at. I have been downloading Kentucky elevation data from [THIS](https://kygeonet.maps.arcgis.com/apps/mapviewer/index.html?webmap=785e6040154e4050bda80049fc12d4a6) website. You can see that there is a really high resolution, and I am able to see the geologic features in great detail on the website. [image: Kentucky Elevation Data Website Screenshot]

The nature preserve falls into the two tiles N065E238 and N066E238. When I upload the TIF file from the Kentucky Elevation Data tiles by dragging the file into QGIS, it looks blurry/has less resolution.
[image: Screenshot of QGIS with bad resolution of data]

I've played around a bit with QGIS and have not found a solution. If anyone is able to help, I would appreciate it if you broke down your explanation into beginner-friendly terms. (BTW. I am self-teaching myself QGIS, so I apologize for any gaps in knowledge or terminology.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have downloaded a digital elevation model (DEM). The top screenshot is showing a hillshade.

You can either style the DEM as a hillshade or create a hillshade.

Style <kbd>F7</kbd>:

[image]

The same layer with Hillshade styling:

[image]

If you want a persistent hillshade that you can save to file use some of the processing tools <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> to create it:

[image]